# Bash - curl command line executes poorly

Tags: linux, bash, curl, couchdb, nosql

I did a bash script to upload a DB on couchDB,
But the final command that is executed with bash to upload a document is not working, while it works perfectly fine if I just launch the same command in the command line.

Here is the bash code :

```
id="$(curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:5984/_uuids?count=1)"
command="curl -X PUT -d ${A} http://chococo:chococo@127.0.0.1:5984/test/${id:11:32}"
echo "Let's try the command "
echo "${command}"
${command}
```

And it does something like that :

```
curl: (3) [globbing] bad range in column 2
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 4
Let's try the command 
curl -X PUT -d '{"evaluation": "none"}' http://chococo:chococo@127.0.0.1:5984/test/2d7811268e98b62d91be1e7cd028e021
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched brace in column 1
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: "evaluation",
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: "none"
```

And if I do the same command in the command line it works great

```
curl -X PUT -d '{"evaluation": "none"}' http://chococo:chococo@127.0.0.1:5984/test/2d7811268e98b62d91be1e7cd028e021
```

What is the mistake here ?

Comment: You don't need the braces in the variable name as you are not indirectly executing a command but rather referencing the contents and so: A='{"evaluation": "none"}' and then reference A with "$A"

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Raman, but it gives the same result though; I still have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your script is because you are storing the command in a variable and executing it indirectly through `$command`.  Storing commands in a string for later execution is a bad idea.  See this page to understand why: [BashFAQ/050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Change the last line in your script to this and you will be fine:

```
curl -X PUT -d "${A}" http://chococo:chococo@127.0.0.1:5984/test/${id:11:32}
```

Comment: Hello, it seems to work better, but it says 
    {"error":"bad_request","reason":"invalid_json"}
now

Comment: there is no reason though, it still works in the command line ... :/

Comment: How are you setting `A` in your script?

Comment: test='{"evaluation": "none"}'
   ...    test="'$test'"
     ...  echo "$test"
      ... curl -X PUT -d ${test}  http://chococo:chococo@127.0.0.1:5984/test/${id:11:32}

Comment: please help guys